# ios - I had successfully connected a storyboard UIWebView to the controller for iPhone, but can not do it for iPad

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview

I created a UIWebView property for the iPhone screens by dragging the iPhone storyboard screen to the .h file, but I am not sure how I can connect the iPad screens to the same controller.

Is there a way they can reuse that same property that I had made?

This is the property that was created:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *theWebView;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you don't have a separate .xib (or storyboard file) file for the ipad?  If not, why not make one, just file new, and pick the nib file (or storyboard file), and make sure its selected for ipad.  Make sure that you set the proper class on the .xib (or storyboard) file if you create a new one.

You can also add a webview problematically if you prefer to do that, something like the following:

```
[self.view addsubview:self.theWebView];
```

Just make sure that you give the webview the appropriate frame to position it where you want and give it the size that you want.

Comment: I do have 2 files, one for each storyboard.  I am just not sure how to connect the iPad storyboboard to use the property that the iPhone storyboard uses. The controller is recognized and is working.

Comment: Simply right click on the webview, or control+click and then drag to a yellow box at the bottom of the storyboard viewcontroller, the options for connections will then appear and you should be able to pick theWebView from, it.

Answer (score 1):

To share a View Controller, you'd need to modify it in the iPad Story Board.

Choose the iPad Story Board, then select the View Controller you want to share with the iPhone one, and pull up the `Identity Inspector`  (3rd icon from the left) right next to the `Attributes Inspector`  You will see a `Class` selection.  Change that to use the same View Controller your iPhone View Controller with the UIWebView is using.

Comment: thank you, I am slightly not following. When I go to the identity inspector of the screen, I already do have the class set.  I think the controller is being connected with the right screen. It is just the property is not working for some reason.

Comment: If you have Class set correctly, you should be able to connect the UIWebView on your iPad view to the UIWebView property you have already made.  That way they will be treated the same.